# Docusign Posts Null/Nothing on Registered web-hook

Tags: docusignapi

**I'm successfully able to create envelop and send a document for a sign, Here is output of my code**

[image]

**Here is my hook registered in DocuSign**

[image]

**And this is the code of my webhook in which I'm just dumping request into file.**

[image]

**And when I complets the document Docusign send push notification to this url, and in that notification it sends nothing, I've tested it 4 times....**

[image]

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you trying sending POST message from POSTMAN or any other REST utility to your listener, and see if your code dumps that message?

Comment: Also try to get Raw POST Data - <?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>, and see whats the output for this

Comment: Yes @AmitKBist I've tested it with post call by using postman and it worked,
Postman: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kTEOp2fZPqts3fTMxfn4Cy5cqurYUKla

Logged Request: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H22pCb2cAbC06tbqkC4cCXM6PAqqcIPk

Comment: Still Docusign posts null on this webhook

Comment: Don't post form data, add Content-Type as `text/xml` in the header and send an XML like `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0'><EnvelopeStatus><AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation><EnvelopeIdStamping>false</EnvelopeIdStamping><AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy><DocumentStatuses><DocumentStatus><ID>1</ID><Name>Doc.pdf</Name></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>` in raw option

Comment: Thanks @AmitKBist , I think I've got the issue by your suggestion,
It is posting XML and my code isn't dumping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print_r() doesn't seem to handle $_REQUEST or $_POST in a way that's particularly useful. Try this instead:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$req_dump = print_r( $request, true );
```

then file_put_contents as you have it

Comment: isn't this the same thing which I pasted in my comment?